# Data is not appending to the body after I click button (Ajax)

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is what my server.js file looks like:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extname: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(3000);

var data = {
    films: [
      {
        title: "Dark Knight",
        director: "Chris Nolan",
        year: 2008
      },
      {
        title: "Inception",
        director: "Chris Nolan",
        year: 2010
      },
      { 
        title: "Inside Out",
        director: "Peter Something",
        year: 2015
      }
    ]
};

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('index.html');
});

app.get('/api/films', function(req, res) {
    console.log("working");
    res.send(data.films);
});

app.get('/api/films/:id', function(req, res) {
    console.log("workinggg");
    res.send(data.films[req.params.id]);
});

app.get('/api/films/:id', function(req, res) {
    console.log("workinggg");
    res.send(data.films[req.params.id]);
});
```

My HTML file with a simple display button:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AJAX</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>FILMS</h1>
    <button>Display Film</button>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Last but not least, my app.js file:

```
console.log("working");

$("button").click(function(){
    console.log("click works!");

    $.ajax({
      url: '/api/films'
  }).done(function(data) {

    $.each(data.films, function(key, value) {
        var title = data[0];
        var director = data[1];
        var year = data[2];
        console.log(title, data, year);
            $('body').append('Director': + director);
    });
  });
});
```

The click function is working but everything after that, nothing works. Nothing will display when I click the button. Neither the console.log. According to my console, it says that there is a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" error on jquery.min.js:2 but I have no clue what this means. Can anyone explain what the issue is?

My data:

```
var data = {
    films: [
      {
        title: "Dark Knight",
        director: "Chris Nolan",
        year: 2008
      },
      {
        title: "Inception",
        director: "Chris Nolan",
        year: 2010
      },
      { 
        title: "Inside Out",
        director: "Peter Something",
        year: 2015
      }
    ]
};
```

Comment: First, you have a small error, the colon after 'Director': Then, you try to use data[0] but you should use value[0]

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the text with a tag like this:

```
$('body').append('<p>Director:' + director + '</p>');
```

Are you sure the each function is written well?

```
$.each(data.films, function(key, value) {
        var title = value[0];
        var director = value[1];
        var year = value[2];
        console.log(title, value, year);
        $('body').append('Director:' + director);
    });
```

Consider changing the data into value.

Comment: Hey I fixed everything by changing data to value and wrapping the text with a tag like how you posted, and this time, after refreshing the page and clicking display films, I get a "Paused in debugger" pop up and I get immediately directed to line 358 of my jquery.js file, which is "length = obj.length,"   Any idea?

Comment: Can you show us the 'data' that is returned from the ajax call '.done(function(data)'

Comment: Yes, the data is this:

Comment: var data = {
 films: [
   {
    title: "Dark Knight",
    director: "Chris Nolan",
    year: 2008
   },
   {
    title: "Inception",
    director: "Chris Nolan",
    year: 2010
   },
   { 
    title: "Inside Out",
    director: "Peter Something",
    year: 2015
   }
 ]
};

Comment: I added the data in readable code format on my original post. Ignore my last comment.

Comment: I suppose you need to parse this data with JSON.
Try to use this function: data = $.parseJSON(data).
This should convert the string into readable array.